# Complex Cron Job Timing - Linux

Tags: unix, cron

I have a complex cron I need to run and I can't find out how. New to crons so I'm sure it's obvious:

- From 7:30 am to 5:00pm Monday thru Friday

  - run command every 25th and 55th minute of the hour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in the root crontab. (if you have that access) Command: `sudo crontab -e`

Then inside:

```
55 7-16 1-5 * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script
25 8-16 1-5 * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script
```

You might have to change the first path depending on where your php binary is located. If so `whereis php` will help you out.